# Fetch string from http response body to array in Jmeter

Tags: regex, groovy, jmeter, httpresponse

**Hello guys
I want to fetch Ids from the HTTP response body and store it in array to use it again in another HTTP request.

I want to be stored like this format {961418ee-9660-4a00-a3b9-10af37e53f02,70287416-26ab-4782-9cef-73c40f17ab7e,a44cc59d-1930-4db5-9898-039bddb9e182,...}

the number of Ids will change every day so I want a dynamic way to fetch id whatever the number of ids.
This is the response body I got:

```
        <select multiple="multiple" id='SMSFarmerlstBox1' class="form-control" style="overflow: auto;">
                <option value="961418ee-9660-4a00-a3b9-10af37e53f02">هديل  ربيحات </option>
                <option value="55c07514-7e09-4acf-9ee1-a27670230887">منى مفلح الخليفات </option>
                <option value="f5675c08-d636-4e8f-b582-6314f7edbc26">جهاد  النادي </option>
                <option value="bd379320-8dd4-4b64-8f30-c7c9675f924e">سيرين  العدوان </option>
                <option value="7230434f-08bb-44e5-99d1-a792d446cac6">sofian test sofianTest1 </option>
                <option value="eadd3b5b-439c-486b-bb9d-ef93cdf6b97d">احمد حسني العوامرة </option>
                <option value="d810916e-042d-463d-b306-a15b08bfe908">سالم علي الرواجفة </option>
                <option value="8bffd494-d2ab-49e6-af4d-845a0a40ee32">يحيى عطا الله السعيدات </option>
                <option value="00bc8098-18a5-4843-99ae-c6c0e41a5985">جميل علي البلاونة </option>
                <option value="6ecd3bd9-db71-47ac-8511-e6b535250bf4">sameer sameer sameer </option>
                <option value="4d3a277e-ea52-4b02-a4c6-2f779bff338a">شاكر محمود عطيه </option>
                <option value="59efb63c-7678-4f71-a83b-9dfaf322f09b">احمد سليمان السعيدات </option>
                <option value="86e826b6-90e8-453a-920e-1588e6b294b1">محمود ابراهيم الحميدات </option>
                <option value="6496ab11-9d09-4e9f-bbd5-24b725f09550">زيدان ارشيد مصطفى </option>
                <option value="50c085d9-de73-4822-bcc9-0641f407c700">زياد محمد العمرات </option>
                <option value="a44cc59d-1930-4db5-9898-039bddb9e182">مطالب اسماعيل السعيدات </option>
                <option value="922fdfd4-85a7-4e70-998a-342956e36313">موسى احمد خليل </option>
                <option value="69ef5a87-50eb-4b83-8eb4-ee8a80f77a0c">احمد مذيب الحوراني </option>
                <option value="81858d1d-5f47-48de-af49-55deffa6dd5d">هلا - هلا٢ </option>
                <option value="5b39e72e-af6c-4d63-a516-00e798370d73">محمد سليم الياصجين </option>
                <option value="d3ac5f58-3cab-421b-81f0-5781d47a4666">يحيى اسماعيل الرواضية </option>
                <option value="f749d825-33e8-440c-b69b-a57b1db61d3b">طارق عطا الله الرواجفة </option>
                <option value="9d2232a1-a6de-49dd-9458-ca2f42199970">بسام سعدو الدسوقي </option>
                <option value="ff5654d8-3e29-4084-b25e-8525c349a360">محمد علي الرواضية </option>
                <option value="8c773f6a-82be-4773-b2d5-fc63fa6eab86">abed  arab </option>
                <option value="965d8e80-5e41-4139-8178-0140f02ee07d">2 3 2 </option>
                <option value="a5144925-42b4-4a09-8d68-6b7d30ad8a9e">NSQAC SESD RSS </option>
                <option value="59b52222-c609-4ae4-8cf3-07c508bdce08">راشد محمد علاونة </option>
                <option value="d8890289-d04d-4e59-9649-c54c37e9a57e">1234 1234 1234 </option>
                <option value="c53d5d8d-c85d-42fc-b52c-b01171cdf5bd">حمد محمد الوارسنة </option>
                <option value="70287416-26ab-4782-9cef-73c40f17ab7e">أمين عبد الرحمن الحسين </option>
                <option value="303dbf57-8042-4e08-9aac-6a45a7c2f531">عطا خضر بركة </option>
                <option value="919caf07-0b6d-481b-a40e-638ef5efbe02">ه  ه </option>
                <option value="02582111-905c-48f2-b22b-03b9f90f2aeb">3 2 3 </option>
                <option value="cc21678d-808f-4ee8-8aa2-91d32c787e88">samer samer samer </option>
                <option value="7c4e43df-2a8a-4dfd-8866-fb3fcef6fabb">هديل  ربيحات </option>
                <option value="eaf9ba4f-64c8-4426-9015-cb48bd85b596">حسين عطية الخلايفة </option>
                <option value="ec27b4da-d75d-4718-8097-1085bda248a5">معروف نافع الطالب </option>
                <option value="eeaf651d-7c6e-4885-ad25-4b8c98813902">هلا111 هلا هلا11 </option>
                <option value="d61660d9-0997-4f66-8fe2-bf42c770ec1e">ssss  sssssss </option>
                <option value="cc9a243d-d283-47c3-9b8c-20caed54c6bd">طارق ذياب الحسين </option>
                <option value="21173029-9e4e-4108-a422-da25cecb677a">عادل حسن اسعد </option>
                <option value="a8401fb4-c7cc-424c-afb4-72016f5b041d">أحمد حافظ  الشوبكي </option>
                <option value="29ca1d99-d2d2-4c30-a885-8f57d81104b6">ناصر سعدو الدسوقي </option>
                <option value="19783201-1889-453f-92ad-e34393af9439">كمال سليمان عميد </option>
                <option value="7342e0c0-5723-4a3e-823f-61b6ebcee14a">هرون موسى الفرجات </option>
                <option value="a2cfabfe-8ce0-45c7-a459-bc2212620049">هديل تحديث هديل ربيحات </option>
                <option value="a9c8b51f-3075-495e-9f73-57c1a8669a7b">سفيان - - </option>
                <option value="2332de19-866e-4bd9-ad03-bdd4726146f7">محمود محمد الذخران </option>
                <option value="82bd9b33-2d2e-480c-b4f6-dbc52af54742">sofian test test </option>
                <option value="45d4fa08-bc58-4bf5-8971-a7b63b6384ac">سفيان فحص1 2 </option>
                <option value="1355aeb9-c6b5-4008-af3b-12fad154d076">هلا  الدبوش </option>
                <option value="2800d8d0-e0da-4131-bca8-cc2078e1844c">أحمد سليمان الشوبكي </option>
                <option value="6f4a9f46-6316-45ee-8c0a-6d004ad44a4d">احمد احمد احمد </option>
                <option value="1d0cc550-41c1-481a-b22b-4414524975bc">محجم مخلد الفقيد </option>
                <option value="e5619869-3432-467e-9117-8f3fa13b3827">اكرم محمد عويفة </option>
                <option value="4eed3d5d-0584-49d7-bf19-029d4a8533c8">اسماعيل عبد الرحمن عليم </option>
                <option value="380a7cd0-c884-42c5-b298-8994f5075541">1 1 1 </option>
                <option value="c0067d59-750e-4c44-b1b4-93a0c774b2e9">علي محمد الشطي </option>
                <option value="12830601-d218-43ae-8060-3bbd0e060eb9">سلمان مطلق العمدات </option>
                <option value="44d5d431-c5aa-4db9-a225-f2a0cc88dc81">وصفي عبد الكريم حسن </option>
                <option value="c00e00a4-4be0-45d2-b6d9-e11d138383c7">عبد الله خليل خليفات </option>
                <option value="a14cd05a-de76-4b5a-8cb7-310a57b578db">ابراهيم علي السلاين </option>
                <option value="8deafaad-997f-4a55-86ce-508664e5034d">1234  1234 </option>
                <option value="ad4dac2d-3a70-45c1-bdda-bae751f5362c">وليد عمر الفقيد </option>
                <option value="57c30ec9-f4b3-4307-b500-3ff563669373">رائد ذياب الحسين </option>
                <option value="8c4934c5-41f3-4732-bf87-2166806bbf52">huawi  10 </option>
                <option value="f9a6bbcf-a6e1-4530-bec8-34eee8b9fbd6">test  huawi </option>
                <option value="f4450dcd-6010-4e9c-a756-26d5f80464e7">اسماعيل  سلمان السعيدات </option>
                <option value="5b7cc3a5-d6fa-45c6-83cc-e5acc98d0b57">aa aa aa </option>
                <option value="ccd767d2-63fa-4756-8ce0-389ae181e0d7">أحمد عاطف مشرقي </option>
                <option value="38e8936a-0036-4043-bd90-46b39dab2bf6">صلاح سليمان الجلابنة </option>
                <option value="7c581aba-6671-4767-86c9-f8ee1dbccf0d">احمد علي الجنيدات </option>
                <option value="b452e183-b55a-4eb4-9007-d99fcae8a368">5 5 5 </option>
                <option value="89c96fad-80d0-40f1-8648-d87f452ea638">سلام احمد الفقيد </option>
                <option value="1a9ccf3f-e613-46b0-b72d-fb756ee80ecb">نوال سالم احمد </option>
                <option value="43b54a56-5e8c-4904-9d15-dfa72728445e">أحمد  عبد الفتاح </option>
                <option value="2ddb6666-684b-41ac-903f-dd0ea86db22e">1 1 1 </option>
                <option value="51672174-59bd-4a56-9681-5ff4ac944ecf">هلا علي &lt;&gt; </option>
                <option value="231d10a5-b959-4156-a6bb-b703b73cbb76">سفيان - - </option>
                <option value="14cc8f4b-1279-4ca8-8fcf-1dcd00e6612c">Mohammad  Saleem </option>
                <option value="510fae2b-4678-446c-a715-232bdc4d74a6">محمد متعب العمارين </option>
                <option value="403b7d7b-aaf2-4143-99bc-21ff664ea582">aa aa aa </option>
                <option value="29c12e1f-104e-4334-9370-d2ee61121215">سمير سلمان فريج </option>
                <option value="dee212a4-d3b3-4b6d-bfde-29c2996fd29d">فاطمة محمد جبارات </option>
                <option value="298aeb06-3fad-4e7d-91ce-0fdb468b5f48">Basima Ehsan Jaarah </option>
                <option value="94333b41-1493-43ad-a93e-e78e494631e4">NSQAC SESD RSS </option>
                <option value="53fdd6bd-a418-44fa-ac5c-013b2c39723b">1 22 1 </option>
                <option value="e3d358fd-2749-4e1c-b893-6695487a6524">zuhair - - </option>
                <option value="f18477f1-009e-40df-96ae-ff0a05dd91de">١ تحديث هديل ١ </option>
                <option value="5d7f85d5-496c-494b-b39c-f5f237839d91">اسماعيل حمودة السلامين </option>
                <option value="359857c6-9d7d-4da2-9d29-a197ebc006f8">سهام  احمد السيد </option>
                <option value="05e63a59-7999-473c-a09c-0c918beb4a22">موسى حميد الخلايفة </option>
                <option value="a907d000-8f04-451b-8b13-8502f5b5e472">شجاع محمد مناور </option>
                <option value="a54f46d5-0b02-4160-a8a5-4dbab999d8ff">Mohammad   Elayyan </option>
                <option value="13a7ea60-451a-4f8e-8a1b-e213481ef249">خلدون رشيد شواهين </option>
                <option value="a945a360-eb24-477e-bacd-37f6869818ad">علي سليم الحسين </option>
                <option value="3a327459-9917-40fa-917d-4ae5aadccff0">هديل  ربيحات </option>
                <option value="411d06c0-5298-4f94-98f9-266d53343277">ابراهيم محمد العموش </option>
                <option value="0464f0b1-d36c-42d4-abff-9cea4dfaf5c8">خير توفيق حمادة </option>
                <option value="8a108741-d090-4820-80fa-238a5362c1db">يوسف عبد الرحمن الحسين </option>
                <option value="02b15d9c-9ac3-44db-98a8-c7969f1bcc26">ثامر  طلال </option>
                <option value="b934da7e-fb3a-45b5-8494-5b39a3bc3e72">خالد رشيد عطيه </option>
                <option value="38d52718-7c1d-4c17-bba1-228fae2be549">حسن موسى حسين </option>
                <option value="a8987b25-d975-4c46-951d-92839f6c4f26">aaa aaa aaa </option>
                <option value="79a15961-eead-4d21-b416-a5aef55f4592">يوسف  موسى ابو عيادة </option>
                <option value="93a17c97-a25d-4b27-800b-13473e84acf3">عبد الله فايق الفلحات </option>
                <option value="450fae33-9d80-4d55-963b-a3a2d5948d6f">deema deema deema </option>
                <option value="8478525b-f161-4ced-93e2-237b7ef3e39e">e  e </option>
                <option value="d94d6d31-9102-4652-a411-9ad73dc0c469">aa aa a </option>
                <option value="66f81d48-8926-46ab-94fb-2cd28f6ff777">12345 1 1 </option>
                <option value="e8dccb35-ada0-4086-b8ac-54bd243bbedc">أنور فتحي الشوبكي </option>
                <option value="16c5fa9c-60ed-4505-b356-7b9044a90635">احمد محمد الحوارات </option>
                <option value="131360dc-24db-4239-ae12-0a3a09f87423">عبد الله ابراهيم عباس </option>
                <option value="c2db54a7-334b-4252-9770-ab9455ebec9a">هديل  ربيحات </option>
                <option value="d419347f-e47a-4d5a-af57-a932b6882464">نواف كريم العبدالله </option>
                <option value="c742d1f6-09a1-4e51-b256-b04f69b14cc6">فؤاد عبد العزيز الجبارات </option>
                <option value="70e06e00-c6d2-45e0-a63b-abe2597ddf36">Sultan Ali AlZoubi </option>
                <option value="f2896bab-26dc-44bf-b4dc-d5642b1ac11c">Sultan  Al-Zoubi </option>
                <option value="543a6a9a-edf9-4465-a266-7d3e8bdb158f">Muath Ahmad Abu Khurma </option>
                <option value="aaec7488-0a70-48ea-bd4f-a9b473e7062c">3 3 3 </option>
                <option value="bae5dda1-73dd-4da8-9c97-ea6c484bbb16">فتحي محمد الشوبكي </option>
                <option value="610c52a8-83ca-443f-9559-fc71f9ef6aa4">بكر ابراهيم الربيع </option>
                <option value="8ed3725f-117c-4854-a162-57b3514b1b19">1234  1234 </option>
                <option value="cfc85544-f1ad-45c4-9faf-68e471646fb0">مي حسن أبو سبيت </option>
                <option value="22fc77e8-a108-467f-854c-10fe4d1895e2">هبة جهاد الشواهين </option>
                <option value="0b941bc9-d771-43c4-9a25-b1976da26a4f">بسام عايش سليمان </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Can anyone save my day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extract all the IDs into JMeter Variables using [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) configured like:

   - Name of created variable: `id`
   - CSS Selector Expression: `select[id=SMSFarmerlstBox1] > option`
   - Attribute: `value`

     [image]
2. Add JSR223 PostProcessor after the CSS Selector Extractor and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def myData = new StringBuilder()
   myData.append('{')
   1.upto(vars.get('id_matchNr') as int, { index ->
       myData.append(vars.get('id_' + index))
       if (index < (vars.get('id_matchNr') as int)) {
           myData.append(',')
       }
   })
   myData.append('}')
   vars.put('myData', myData.toString())
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, now you should be able to refer the value using `${myData}` variable reference where required

More information:

- [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)
- [Groovy cheat sheet](http://pledbrook.github.io/groovy-cheat-sheet/guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer ever on stackoverflow, so pardon me if you find anything wrong.

What we can do here is use the capture groups functionality of regex, you can refer it from here https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups.
I am using javascript, but the basic functionality is same in every language.

```js
const str = `
<select multiple="multiple" id='SMSFarmerlstBox1' class="form-control" style="overflow: auto;">
<option value="70e06e00-c6d2-45e0-a63b-abe2597ddf36">Sultan Ali AlZoubi </option>
<option value="f2896bab-26dc-44bf-b4dc-d5642b1ac11c">Sultan  Al-Zoubi </option>
<option value="543a6a9a-edf9-4465-a266-7d3e8bdb158f">Muath Ahmad Abu Khurma </option>
<option value="aaec7488-0a70-48ea-bd4f-a9b473e7062c">3 3 3 </option>
<option value="bae5dda1-73dd-4da8-9c97-ea6c484bbb16">فتحي محمد الشوبكي </option>
<option value="610c52a8-83ca-443f-9559-fc71f9ef6aa4">بكر ابراهيم الربيع </option>
<option value="8ed3725f-117c-4854-a162-57b3514b1b19">1234  1234 </option>
<option value="cfc85544-f1ad-45c4-9faf-68e471646fb0">مي حسن أبو سبيت </option>
<option value="22fc77e8-a108-467f-854c-10fe4d1895e2">هبة جهاد الشواهين </option>
<option value="0b941bc9-d771-43c4-9a25-b1976da26a4f">بسام عايش سليمان </option>
</select>
</div>`;


const regexExp = /.*value="(.*)"/g;

let matches = str.matchAll(regexExp);
   
const arr_of_ids = [];

for (const match of matches) {
    arr_of_ids.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(arr_of_ids)
```

I have used this regex

> `/.*value="(.*)"/`

What it does is, it captures any character inside `value="  "`, which in our case is the id. You can also run the above code snippet to see the output.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

A groovy no-brain day saver looks like:

```
String input = '''<select multiple="multiple" id='SMSFarmerlstBox1' class="form-control" style="overflow: auto;">
                <option value="961418ee-9660-4a00-a3b9-10af37e53f02">هديل  ربيحات </option>
                <option value="bd379320-8dd4-4b64-8f30-c7c9675f924e">سيرين  العدوان </option>
                <option value="7230434f-08bb-44e5-99d1-a792d446cac6">sofian test sofianTest1 </option>
</whatever>
'''

def list = []
input.eachMatch( /<option value="([^"]+)">/ ){ list << it[ 1 ] }
assert 3 == list.size()
```